# Texture2DMS slice access and bandwidth saving

Tags: directx11

Can we cut bandwidth by `N` (for `N×MSAA`) if we access only one slice of a multisampled texture in a shader ?

I'm thinking of doing a manual resolve in a shader, because some targets may make no sense to average. e.g. depth, encoded normals, IDs..

Unfortunately, the memory layout may be so that MSAA slices are close in memory which means that a fetch nearby would cache the whole line.

A solution to get an answer would be to measure the performance difference of accessing all slices vs 1. But I suppose there are no guarantees of repetition across hardware ?